# Invoke compilers of different languages from within sts/eclipse

Tags: java, compiler-construction, invoke

I have a situation where the user posts a file to server and it needs to be compiled on the  server side. The server should detect the language and invoke the corresponding compiler and send the results back to client. Right now we are supporting Java, Python and C. Is there a way I can compile a Java file which is not imported into eclipse from within eclipse? And also, is there a way I can invoke compilers for python and C (or any other language can be used) from within eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you detect the language of the code this becomes pretty easy:

```
String compiler = "";

switch(compilerCode)
{
    case JAVA:
        compiler = "javac";
    break;
    case C:
        compiler = "javac";
    break;

    ...
 }


 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(compiler + " " + file);
 p.waitFor();
```

`file` will be the name of the file you are trying to compile, and `compilerCode` will be a code that will tell you which compiler to use.

This goes without saying but you should have all of the compilers installed to compile all of the languages you intend on supporting.

---

Edit:

It is super easy to get error messages from a running process. All you need to do is:

```
InputStream in = p.getErrorStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
...
String error = reader.readLine();
...
reader.close();
```

Comment: I have been working under the similar lines and how would i retrieve the errors on compilation/results on running the program from p ? sorry im completely new to using such things thanks !

Comment: @user2707760 thats easy, just do `p.getErrorStream()` and listen for output. If there is no output, then the compilation was usually successful.

Comment: it worked fine for java, but when i try with python it gives a "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" error. I made sure path is pointing to my python home directory. and also can you help me with getting the output on successful compilation i tried to run and retireve the results but it always returns a empty string

Comment: sorry for the confusion, when i try to run the program it gives me a Error: Could not find or load main class C:.users.cvallurupalli.desktop.source.StringExample
for java too...the .class file is actually being created in the path specified.